# Wireshark not found after installing RHEL 5.5

Tags: networking, installation, rhel5, wireshark

After installing `Wireshark` in RHEL 5.5 (32bit) with following command:

```
yum install wireshark
```

Wireshark not found:

> [root@localhost ~]# wireshark bash:
>
> wireshark: command not found

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed command line version of Wireshark (Tshark). Use following command as superuser mode to install Wireshark GUI version:

```
yum install wireshark-gnome
```

Comment: Is there this package on RHEL 5.5 Disc? (My RHEL is not registered,so i can't use RHEL repository)

Comment: Yes. It exist on the disc. _wireshark-gnome_ does not required any package. So feel free to install it from DVD using _rpm --ivh ..._ command.